# Mass create methods for an object

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I know that a new method for an object can be declare like so:

```
var MyObject = function() {return new MyObject.prototype};
MyObject.prototype.exists = function() {alert("The object exists.")};
```

**How can I create many methods as a bunch for MyObject instead of one by one?**

**I have tried**:

```
MyObject.prototype = {
    exists: function() {alert("The object exists.")},
    isBorn: function() {alert("The object is born.")},
    isDead: function() {alert("The object has left our world.")}
}
```

Calling `MyObject.exists()` returns: `Uncaught TypeError: MyObject.exists is not a function`

### **What I am trying to do**:

I am trying to do something like jQuery does.

jQuery is defined like so:

```
jQuery = function(selector, context) {included)
    return new jQuery.fn.init(selector, context);
}
```

We don't say `var j = new jQuery;` when we call it like `jQuery("#foo")`.

Then the files says:

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
    jquery: version,
    constructor: jQuery,
    length: 0,

    toArray: function() {
        return slice.call( this );
    }
    ...
}
```

Isn't `toArray()` a method of the `jQuery` object? Why doesn't it show the same error when I call it.

Comment: Try `,` instead of `;` and omit the last one.

Comment: @LUH3417 sorry that was a typo.

Comment: try `(new MyObject).exists();`

Comment: You need to create an object to access its prototype methods.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with creating multiple methods vs one method. `MyObject.exists()` wouldn't work with the first example either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `jQuery` function is called, you're not creating an instance of `jQuery` which is why you don't use the `new` keyword. Instead, you're returning an **instance** of `jQuery.fn.init`.

Follow it down and you'll see that the prototype of init being declared:

```
init.prototype = jQuery.fn;
```

And the definition for `jQuery.fn` is:

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = { ... };
```

Which means that `(new jQuery.fn.init(selector, context))` has all the methods from `jQuery.prototype`.

So, `toArray` is not a method of the `jQuery` object, but rather a method on the prototype of the return value from calling `jQuery()`.

You can achieve the same thing in fewer steps by manually assigning the prototype of the return value.

```
function MyObject() {
  var obj = {};
  return Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, MyObject.prototype);
}

MyObject.prototype.toArray = function() {};

MyObject().toArray();
```

Comment: I am trying to make object kind of how jQuery works. We don't say `var j = new jQuery;` This kind of happens inside the `function jQuery() {}`. What do I have to return in order to achieve that?

Comment: Just declare the methods directly onto the function then. That's how jQuery does it.

Comment: Yes, but later in the file it says: `jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {...}`. I did the same and just omitted `fn`.

Comment: Give a concrete example of what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to declare methods on the function? Or do you want to declare methods on the return values?

Comment: Check out my edit @DanPrince. It was big to post here.

Comment: That's a great answer @DanPrince. Can I define the methods as shown in the 'I have tried' part of the question? Like: `MyObject.prototype = { method: function() {}, ... }`

Comment: Sure, just remember to return an object that uses that prototype.

Comment: Great. I tested it and I can access the methods. If return `Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, MyObject.prototype);` and not something like jQuery does `return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );`, how will be able to get an element by its id? I have already created an `init()` method that does that, but it would work if written like: `MyObject().init("#foo")`

Comment: `return Object.setPrototypeOf(select(someSelector), MyObject.prototype))`

Comment: Show this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object.setPrototypeOf called on null or undefined

Comment: You must have passed null or undefined. Make sure you implement `select`.

Comment: It doesn't recognise select :( @DanPrince can you check this fiddle and tell me if it makes any sense? https://jsfiddle.net/udLLaw2b/2/

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot for your effort @DanPrince. The fiddle works like a charm and your answer helped me understand better how to use `prototype`.

Comment: I tested for a class and it didn't work. Do you have time to give it a look again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116741/discussion-between-dan-prince-and-angel-politis).

Answer (score 0):

You were very close, you just have to create a new instance of the object for it to inherit from its own prototype chain.

```
var myObj = function () {};
myObj.prototype = {
  a: function () { console.log(1) },
  b: function () { console.log(2) },
  c: function () { console.log(3) }
};
var myObject = new myObj();
myObject.a(); // 1
myObject.b(); // 2
myObject.c(); // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one is still better because prototype objects have predefined properties (currently only `constructor`, but later the standard can be extended), and totally overwriting the prototype object will effectively remove those properties. But still it can be shortened like:

```js
function Foo() {}
const p = Foo.prototype;
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(p));
p.exists = function() { console.log("exists"); };
p.isBorn = function() { console.log("isBorn"); };

(new Foo).exists();
```

But hey, it's 2016! We have javascript classes in most major browsers ([check compatibility at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/hu/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Browser_compatibility))!

```js
class Foo {
  exists() { console.log("exists"); }
  isBorn() { console.log("isBorn"); }
}

(new Foo).exists();
```

Comment: Class is not recognised in older browsers.